# does datanitro stop working after 30 days?

Tags: datanitro

First of all, I have to say datanitro is awesome. I am thinking of using it for non-commercial use. According to the website, it is free for non-commercial use. But all I can do is download the 30 day trial version. On excel, it says 30 days left. Will it stop working after 30 days?

Comment: I have since bought it. But was using the trail for six months. Cannot confirm if newer trial versions have an expiry. Did not see any nag screens either.

Answer (score 6):

The trial does expire after a month. You can see options for purchasing a license [here](https://datanitro.com/pricing.html).

Thanks for trying it out!

(Source: I'm one of the founders.)